# When I enter www.google.com why google is redirecting with new parameters or hash?

Tags: redirect, https

When I enter http://www.google.com in Chrome or any other browser, it redirects to https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=cr&ei=alyXUpSMCOjiywOU8oF4 or something similar with a different hash.

Anybody knows why this is happening ? 
Google is trying to keep track of their users when you bookmark the site in favorites?

Thank you.

Comment: gws_rd=cr means Google Web Server Redirect by Country. ei=???? is a hash indicating your geographical region so that Google knows what the best results to return are when you POST back a search request.

Answer (score 0):

It is Google automatically redirecting you to your closest country. This is done using DNS. The tags are automatically added on.

If you go straight to https://www.google.ie you should not get them.